# Scale values in range (0, 1)

Tags: scikit-learn, scale

I want to scale my values in range (0, 1), but without getting the values 0 and 1, like at **MinMax Scaler**. I was thinking that probably adding something to the **MinMax Scaler** function like:

> x_scaled[i] = (x[i] - min(x) +- something) / (max(x) - min(x) +- something)

so that for the minimum values to get something very small, but not 0, and for the maximum values to get something very close to 1, but not 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html `MinMaxScaler` has a `feature_range` argument which you can set to `(1e-8,1.0-1e-8)` in your case for instance. Should do the trick you are looking for.

Comment: can you give more context on do you want to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `feature_range` as mentioned in the comments.

For `something` you can try to use something more smarter than small value, for example, percentile (0.1 or 0.5 or 1 from the left side and 99 or 99.5 or 99.9 from the right side - depends on your data).

Or it is possible to perform a simpler approach where your `something` will be a rate to `min()` and `max()` values in the scaled column. For example, you can scale from `0.9 * min()` to `1.1 * max()`

PS I suppose that real small value, like `1e-8` maybe rounded somewhere in the code.